# How to deal with dependencies in shared libraries, unix

Tags: linux, dependencies, shared-libraries

I have created a dynamic(.so) library which bundles some functionality for a storage backend that I need.
As it is, it offers a known interface and provides backends for things like memcached, mysql, sqlite... etc.

Now my problem is that my shared library depends on libmemcached, on libsqlite3, on libmysqlclient.. etc., and I don't know how to pack it since clients that only want sqlite wouldn't need to have libmemcached installed.

I've been thinking on splitting it on different libraries but it seems like I'll end up with almost 20 .so libraries and I don't like that idea.

Any alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One alternative is to put an interface within the shared library you made, which allows it to load dependencies at runtime. So, as an example you can have separate
init functions for different components:

```
init_memcached();
init_sqlite();
```

You implement these initialization functions using [dlopen()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) and friends.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [dynamic loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) using `dlsym` and `dlopen`.
The advantage of this approach is your application will run fine when the shared library is not found on client side.

Answer (score 0):

You could load only needed shared libraries during run-time, but in my opinion, it is not so good approach.

I would split the shared library, but not into 20 libraries. See if you could group some common functionality.

Comment: I am curious - why would you not consider the first approach as good?

Comment: @Sudhanshu The problem with that approach is you have to get the address of every needed function, and it works fine for c, but for c++ it requires some juggling (for example providing functions to create and delete objects).